# Mapper writes wrapped value but can't read

Tags: jackson

I need to wrap my json objects to look like this:

```
{
    "user" : { "id":1 }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "id":1
}
```

So I set:

```java
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

The serialization part is working fine:

```java
mapper.writeValue(writer, user);
```

But if I do:

```java
User u = mapper.readValue(writer.toString(), User.class);
```

The returned object contains only null fields. Do I need to configure something else for reading wrapped elements?

Regards

Comment: Nevermind, for somereason my Eclipse was never finding the class DeserializationConfig. To make it worked I just used:mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
  mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
  mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the deserialization configuration counterpart to `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.  It's `DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.  (With Jackson 2+, it's `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.)

Comment: Yep, tks, for some reason eclipse was never finding the class DeserializationConfig, so I thought I only needed the Serialization config part